# Java- Android How to compare two strings with old saved data

Tags: java, android, string, linked-list, sharedpreferences

I'm creating an app where I have to download a string (to be exactly a Linked list) at startup (maybe do that only on first run) and then check this string with a new string downloaded every some time. If there are changes than update the original string with the new found (and alert with a foreground service, but this is another story).

At the moment I created an exeutable service and inside of it I put the code to download and manage the string. It is executed every 15 min, and it works.

My problem is that I'm not sure which is the best way to save the initial data and then how to update it only if found something new. I could create a method on the main or create a different class called by main. Also, to save this data when you turn off the phone or kill the app, I have to save the string in shared preferences?

I would like to know the opinion of someone. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

To persist through a reboot, yes, the data will have to be stored somehow. `SharedPreferences` is a fine way to do this. I assume you have a service running with an `Alarm`, so grab the new value and check the cached one. If it's different, write it. If it's not, you're done.

If you're using a service, you could also try storing the value in memory for quicker comparison. If it reverts to `null`, you know you'll need to fetch the saved value again, otherwise do the same comparison without a read from storage.

You could also use a `BroadcastReceiver` to compare the results, attaching the newly-fetched value as an extra and sending a `Broadcast` once it's retrieved.